# Compile error when trying some Yesod examples

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying `Yesod` book examples documented on Yesod webpage. One of the examples is for [Chat application embedded in Wiki](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/wiki-chat-example). When I try it in ghci (loading `Chat` module from `Wiki.hs` which contains Wiki example code), I get the error below for Chat.hs:

```
Chat.hs:122:34:
    Could not deduce (Text.Julius.ToJavascript Text)
      arising from a use of `Text.Julius.toJavascript'
    from the context (YesodChat master)
      bound by the type signature for
                 chatWidget :: YesodChat master =>
                               (Route Chat -> Route master) -> GWidget sub master ()
      at Chat.hs:(81,15)-(83,35)
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Text.Julius.ToJavascript Text)
    In the first argument of `Text.Julius.Javascript', namely
      `Text.Julius.toJavascript output'
    In the expression:
      Text.Julius.Javascript (Text.Julius.toJavascript output)
    In the first argument of `Data.Monoid.mconcat', namely
      `[Text.Julius.Javascript
          ((Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.fromText . Text.Shakespeare.pack')
             "\
             \// Set up the receiving end\
             \var output = document.getElementById(\""),
        Text.Julius.Javascript (Text.Julius.toJavascript output),
        Text.Julius.Javascript
          ((Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.fromText . Text.Shakespeare.pack')
             "\");\
             \var src = new EventSource(\""),
        Text.Julius.Javascript
          (Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.fromText
             (_render_a3Yr (toMaster ReceiveR) [])),
        ....]'
```

I am not very familiar with Yesod libraries yet. So, I am stumped by the above error - I have seen this error in other Yesod examples too where `toWidget` function is called. So, it seems to be related to `toWidget` function. I will appreciate help in fixing the above error.

I am using `ghc 7.6.1` with `yesod 1.1.4.1`.

**Update:**

Fixed following Hammar's suggestion. I made two changes in `Chat.hs`.

1. Add import statement for rawJS:

   `import Text.Julius (rawJS)`
2. Track down all instances of #{} blocks within `julius whamlet` in `Chat.hs`, and replace them with `{# rawJS ...}`

   `var output = document.getElementById("#{rawJS output}");`

   `var input = document.getElementById("#{rawJS input}");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have Yesod installed to test it at the moment, but according to [this blog post](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/11/updates-julius-interpolation) you should just have to change `#{output}` to `#{rawJS output}` and so on when interpolating JavaScript identifiers.

Comment: thank you, @hammar. That was exactly the problem. Fixed now after I tracked down every #{} block inside julius whamlet, and replaced it with rawJS.

Answer (score 5):

In [`shakespeare-js-1.1.0`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare-js-1.1.0), the `ToJavascript` instances for `Text` and some other types have been removed:

```
-- | A typeclass for types that can be interpolated in CoffeeScript templates.
class ToJavascript a where
    toJavascript :: a -> Builder
#if 0
instance ToJavascript [Char] where toJavascript = fromLazyText . TL.pack
instance ToJavascript TS.Text where toJavascript = fromText
instance ToJavascript TL.Text where toJavascript = fromLazyText
instance ToJavascript Javascript where toJavascript = unJavascript
instance ToJavascript Builder where toJavascript = id
#endif
instance ToJavascript Value where toJavascript = fromValue
```

while in previous versions of the package, they were only conditionally disabled:

```
#ifndef SAFER_INTERPOLATION
```

I don't know whether that's intentional and meant to remain so, or just a forgotten development change.

To use the example as is, you would need to rebuild yesod against `shakespeare-js < 1.1`. That would mean uninstalling a lot of packages first, or a new sandbox (if you're using cabal-dev or some other sandboxing tool).

The only instances of `ToJavascript` in `shakespeare-js-1.1.0` are `RawJavascript` (a `newtype` wrapper around [`Builder`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html#t%3aBuilder)) and [`Value`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.0.2/doc/html/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t%3aValue) (a type for JSON values) from the `aeson` package.

You could just wrap `output` in

```
Text.Julius.toJavascript output
```

in a `RawJavascript . Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.fromText` to get a `RawJavascript` value and make it work if it were real code, but since it's TH-generated, you'd need to fix the TH output or the quasiquoter - neither of which I know how to do.

Comment: Thanks @daniel-fischer. Indeed, rawJS was missing as Hammar pointed out.